# Maximum of poisson and geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I need to find the maximum of geometrich and poisson distribution. I'm not sure if the first part is correct and what to do with No. 2.:

**1. for fixed p I need a k for which $P(X = k)$ is maximized.**

- for $p=1$ we have $P(x = k) = 1 \cdot 0^{k-1}$ which is 1 for k=1 and 0 else.
- for $0 < p < 1$ we have $\frac{P(x=k)}{P(X=k-1)} = \frac{p\cdot q^{k-1}}{p \cdot q^{k-1}\cdot q^{-1}} = \frac{1}{q^{-1}} = q = 1-p < 1$.
- Now $p_n < p_{n-1} \rightarrow p_n$ is strictly monotonuous decreasing and therefore the maximum is at $k = 1$.

**2. I need the $\lambda$ that maximizes the probability for the observations $(x_1, ... ,x_n)$ of poisson distributed random variables $X_i$. [ where $p(x1, . . . , xn) = \Pi_{i=1}^n p(x_i)$.**

- $\frac{p_k}{p_{k-1}} = \frac{e^{-\lambda} \cdot \lambda^k}{k!} \cdot \frac{(k-1)!}{e^{-\lambda}\cdot\lambda^{k-1}}=\frac{\lambda}{k}$
- Now $p_{k-1} < p_k \rightarrow k < \lambda$.
- ???

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You are actually looking for the *mode* rather than the *maximum*.  Your answer for (1) is essentially correct

For (2) you found $p_{k-1} < p_k \iff k < \lambda$

You could also have found $p_{k-1} = p_k \iff k = \lambda$ and $p_{k-1} > p_k \iff k > \lambda$

So the mode occurs for $k$ with $\lambda -1 \le k \le \lambda$